# change time format using sed

Tags: unix, time, sed

I've come across a bunch of files I need to import into my database with an awful time format

```
A09:13:08C
```

not even sure what it stands for
Is there any fast way using sed to replace 'A' by space and delete 'C'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/A(.*)C/ \1/' filename
```

Simply you are saving all the words between **A** and **C** and then using it with **\1**

A more careful sentence would be:

```
sed -r 's/A([0-9:]+)C/ \1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, there is other data on the line, so using a casual `.*` is likely to mangle things.  I'd use a rather verbose but restrictive pattern:

```
sed -e 's/A\([012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\)C/ \1/'
```

This looks for an A followed by a 24-hour clock time value and C, preserving the time portion.  It would accept some invalid times (25-29 as the hour; indeed, 24:00:01 is not normally valid either, but 24:00:00 can be); it would be your judgement call whether it is worth refining these patterns (frankly, I doubt it, but it depends on how well you know your data).

Answer (score 0):

If this is all that is in the file then

```
grep -o '[^AC]\+' file
```

If there are other fields i would use (g)awk.
Where N is the field.

```
awk '{match($1,/([^AC]+)/,x)}$1=x[1]' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks much simplier:

```
tr A ' ' | tr -d C
```

Comment: That works if the only data in the file is the time data, but that is fairly unlikely.